# Two button clicks required for OnValidSubmit after form is invalid

Tags: blazor

Consider the following code snippet:

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<EditForm Model="@person" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="person.Name" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

<p>@message</p>

@code {

    readonly Person person = new();

    string message;

    void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        message = "Name = " + person.Name;
    }

    private class Person
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Steps to replicate the issue:

1. Run the application
2. Do not enter anything in the name text input
3. Click Submit
4. Observe the "Name is required" validation message appears
5. Enter the name "Joe" in the name text input
6. Click Submit
7. Observe the validation message disappears
8. Click Submit again
9. Observe the "Name = Joe" message appears.

It seems that the `OnValidSubmit` event does not fire after the second Submit button click (step 6), even though the form is now valid.  I have to click it again (step 8).  Why is this and how can I get the `OnValidSubmit` to fire at step 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a css problem when you press the button before you release it the button changes the place, so you didn't click the button at all.

Change the code like this

```
<EditForm Model="person" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="person.Name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two overlapping events happening when you use the mouse to shift focus from the input control to the button.

1. You have left the `InputText` so there's an `onChange` event triggered.
2. You have clicked the button so there's an `onClick` event raised.

When the first event occurs the validation changes and the position of the button changes.  The click is on empty space, so no `OnClick` event occurs.